# Como obter o id do elemento a partir de sua class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho a seguinte lista:

```
<ul id = "qualquer">
    <li id = "listitem1" class = "middle_item">
    </li>
    <li id = "listitem2">
    </li>
    <li id = "listitem3">
    </li>
</ul>
```

No meu problema, a `class = "middle_item"` pode estar em qualquer `li`, mas neste momento, por acaso, situa-se na primeira `li`.

Criei o seguinte javascript, para tentar apanhar o `id` da `li` que tem a `class = "middle_item"`

```
var i = $("#qualquer .middle_item").attr('id').text();
        alert(i);
```

mas está a aparecer-me o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).attr(...).text is not a function

Alguma sugestão?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nj3c9aoj/)

Comment: Se `middle_item` tiver só um elemento, basta fazer `$($('.middle_item')[0]).attr('id');`, não?

Comment: Vc quer fazer oq? Mostrar o conteudo da li?

Comment: Falha minha, eu criei este exemplo para simplificar o problema original. O `middle_item` tem mais do que um elemento

Comment: Mas você quer pegar o `id` de todos os `middle_items`?

Comment: @JeffersonAlison eu pretendo mostrar o id da li

Comment: @FelipeAvelar Não. Só quero apanhar o id da li que tem a class `middle_item`

Comment: Mas se várias `li`s podem ter `middle_item`, então terão vários ids...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes fazer isso só com JavaScript nativo:

```
var id = document.querySelector('.middle_item').id;
```

Em relação ao erro `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).attr(...).text is not a function`, o problema que essa mensagem de erro aponta é que quando usas `.attr('id')` isso vai retornar uma string com a `id` que queres. Tentar aplicar o método `.text()` à id (*string*) dá naturalmente erro.

Ou seja, podes usar jQuery: `var id = $("#qualquer .middle_item").attr('id')`, mas só com JavaScript nativo é mais rápido. No caso de não existir nenhum elemento no DOM com essa classe ambas vão dar erro. O jQuery dá Mas se fizeres assim (como em baixo) já não vai dar:

```
var el = document.querySelector('.middle_item');
var id = el && el.id;
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lrhf958g/

Comment: Sergio, mais um ponto pro seu currículo :)

Comment: @Lollipop obrigado :) eu gosto de ajudar a perceber problemas como este.

Comment: Só pra complementar, no seu segundo exemplo não dá erro e `id` terá o valor `false` caso o elemento não exista.

Answer (score 2):

Para mostrar somente o id da li que esta com a class middle_item:

```
var i = $("#qualquer .middle_item").attr("id");
alert(i);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeffersonalison/nj3c9aoj/1/)